# Accidentally deleted Ivy. Now what?

Tags: package, package-repositories, ivy

I went to `M-x list-packages` and accidentally deleted Ivy.

How do I get it back in `M-x list packages` now?

Comment: It should still be there, but labelled `available` instead of e.g. `dependency`. You can install it again via `M-x package-install RET ivy RET` or by typing `RET` on its entry in the `*Packages*` buffer and then clicking on the `Install` button in the `*Help*` window.

Comment: Alternatively (and equivalently) you can type `i` or `M-x package-menu-mark-install RET` on its entry in the `*Packages*` buffer, followed by `x` or `M-x package-menu-execute RET`.

Comment: @Basil Perfect. Your first solution worked. I was under an impression (wrongly) that `list packages` lists ALL pakcages (including available packages).

Comment: The sorting in the `*Packages*` buffer is per default on `status`, not on package name, so that installed and not installed packages are separated by quite some vertical line distance. You can resort by moving point to the first char on the package name and press `S`.

Comment: It *does* list *all* packages, like I said - even after deletion, the package is still there, but it is labelled with a different status, as @p_wiersig elaborates.